# Python xpath пустой массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, xpath

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так может быть:
xpath помощник результат показувает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

insta_url = f'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/торт/?hl=ru'

response = session.get(insta_url)

print(response)

vsego = response.html.xpath('//div//span[@class="g47SY "]//text()')

print(vsego)
```

получаем в итоге пустой массив

Comment: У вас пробел в атрибуте.

Comment: Все правильно. В xpath на картинке он тоже есть.

Comment: В таком случае надо смотреть, что присылает сайт. Может, оно в зависимости от юзерагента отдаёт различную вёрстку.